# Xamarin Blank App (Native) template missing in Visual Studio 2015

Tags: xamarin, visual-studio-2015

I have installed all the tools for development with Xamarin in Visual Studio 2015, but somehow I do not see Blank App (Native) template when I create new project. I am only able to use Blank Apps (Xamarin Forms) template. I have already tried to reinstall Xamarin, reinstall Visual Studio install all the Xamarin sdks separately, but still no success. Have you please any idea, how to get the template to the list?

Comment: Can you post your version info in a gist? It's likely that Xamarin has not installed properly / is not being initialised. `Help -> About Microsoft Visual Studio -> Copy Info`

Comment: Hi BytesGuy here is the info related to Xamarin: Microsoft Visual Studio Enterprise 2015
Version 14.0.24720.00 Update 1
Microsoft .NET Framework
Version 4.6.01586
Installed Version: Enterprise

Xamarin   4.1.2.18 (fcbe082)
Visual Studio extension to enable development for Xamarin.iOS and Xamarin.Android.

Xamarin.Android   6.1.2.21 (1cf254d)
Visual Studio extension to enable development for Xamarin.Android.

Xamarin.iOS   9.8.2.22 (f37444a)
Visual Studio extension to enable development for Xamarin.iOS.

Comment: @BytesGuy can you please provide me an advice based on info from gist? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Try this(from [msdn](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt488769.aspx#missing)):

> In Control Panel, open Programs and Features, choose the Xamarin item,
>   and click Change. In the setup wizard for Xamarin that appears, click
>   Next and then Change. In the list of optional features to install,
>   expand Xamarin for Visual Studio 2015, choose will be installed on
>   local drive, and click Next to proceed with adding the feature.

Comment: Hi FetFrumos, thank you for your answer however as I write in my question, I have already tried this process.

Answer (score 0):

VS 2015 caches a lot and that usually means a lot of troubles.

Close Visual Studio 2015.

After **restoring** Xamarin, go to C:\Users\**user_name**\AppData\Local\Microsoft\VisualStudio\14.0\VTC and type on the search box **cache.bin**

NOTE - You will only see those files if you set the [show hidden files](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/14201/windows-show-hidden-files) option.

Delete all **cache.bin** files.

Reopen VS2015. All your Xamarin templates will be there and they show the appropriate icon.

Answer (score 0):

Visual Studio updated **Xamarin Blank App** option to **Mobile App (Xamarin.Forms).** Once you have selected the **Mobile App (Xamarin.Forms)** option, you can create a **Blank App** as you like.
I make an creating directions GIF.
[image: Creating Xamarin Blank App in Visual Studio 2017 (Animated GIF)]