# Visual studio 2015 and Xamarin Form portable under cross platform

Tags: c#, jquery, xaml, xamarin, xamarin.android

I installed visual studio 2015 and Xamarin. But i didnt see Blank App (Xamarin form potable) under cross platform menu. How to make it work?

Comment: have you seen this..http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39039439/xamarin-blank-app-native-template-missing-in-visual-studio-2015...

still if you are facing the problem, try to re-install xamarin

Answer (score 0):

At this time, maybe it could be cool if you use the newest version of Visual Studio (VS 2017). Have more issue solving than VS 2015.

With 2015 I solved that issue by downloading and installing the Xamarin Tools from [Xamarin.com/download](http://xamarin.com/download) website.